# Why is std::string's empty rep the way it is?

Tags: c++, string

In the GNU implementation of `std::string`, its `_S_empty_rep_storage` is defined as:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
  typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type
  basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage[
    (sizeof(_Rep_base) + sizeof(_CharT) + sizeof(size_type) - 1) / sizeof(size_type)
  ];
```

Why is it defined in terms of `size_type` rather than simply `char`?  Why isn't it defined as:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
  _CharT
  basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage[
    sizeof(_Rep_base) + sizeof(_CharT)
  ];
```

?

FYI: The reason I'm asking is because I'm implementing my own string class
(that has different requirements that `std::string` doesn't meet)
so I'd like to understand as much as possible as to how `std::string` is implemented.

Comment: Because the result is not the same?

Comment: "rather than simply char" <- Did you mean to say "rather than simply _CharT" there?

Comment: "implementing my own string class" has question marks written all over it.  Are you absolutely sure you need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The size of _CharT may vary, in particular if you're using wchar_t rather than char.

I realise that only answers part of the question.  I'm not sure why the Rep_base stuff is defined the way it is, but in general with the STL it's best to not worry too much about how it works; just be happy that it does.

Because you're very (very) unlikely to find a bug that fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

Alignment and rounding. The `+ sizeof(size_type) - 1) / sizeof(size_type)` part rounds up to the next higher number of `size_type` elements.

Comment: I understand the rounding.  What wasn't clear was the alignment.  However, I would think that you would get "better" alignment (not to mention clearer code) if a simple _CharT array were put as the only thing inside a plain struct that would (of course) guarantee proper struct alignment which I think is what you'd want since the storage is for a "rep" which is a struct (class).